# Laravel Authentication Why im getting data from other model or database table but in model itself it cannot?

Tags: laravel, authentication, eloquent, model, laravel-6

The problem is, when I try to login using suitspecialist login it wont login using credentials from suitspecialist database table. however, it will login when I use credentials from blogger database table in suitspecialist login form.

really weird

Note:blogger login works fine just the suitspecialist login and I can register and store data to suitspecialist databe table ..

**This is my blogger model**

```
class Blogger extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $guard = 'blogger';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**Suitspecialist model**

```
class Suitspecialist extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'suitspecialist';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**Login controller of blogger**

```
 public function showBloggerLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.login', ['url' => 'blogger']);
}

public function bloggerLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('blogger')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

        return redirect()->intended('/blogger');
    }
    return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

**Login controller of suitspecialist**

```
public function showSuitspecialistLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.login', ['url' => 'suitspecialist']);
}

public function suitspecialistLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('suitspecialist')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

        return redirect()->intended('/suitspecialist');
    }
    return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your 'model' attribute in `config/auth.php`. I think it is set to 'blogger'. Change it to the model you to use for authentication.

Comment: Bro I tried to debug  this for 2 days. problem solved
Thanks ! love yahh hahahaha